# git diff giving wrong information

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have just added one single line in file in intellij idea, but my git diff is showing the lines which I haven't changed.

example:

```
-- Guest OS mappings for VMware 6.5
SELECT INSERT_INTO_GUEST_OS_HYPERVISOR(UUID(), 'VMware', '6.5', 'debian9Guest', (select id from guest_os where display_name='Debian GNU/Linux 9 (32-bit)' LIMIT 1), utc_timestamp(), 0);

SELECT INSERT_INTO_GUEST_OS_HYPERVISOR(UUID(), 'VMware', '6.5', 'debian9_64Guest', (select id from guest_os where display_name='Debian GNU/Linux 9 (64-bit)' LIMIT 1), utc_timestamp(), 0);

SELECT INSERT_INTO_GUEST_OS_HYPERVISOR(UUID(), 'VMware', '6.5', 'debian10Guest', (select id from guest_os where display_name='Debian GNU/Linux 10 (32-bit)' LIMIT 1), utc_timestamp(), 0);

SELECT INSERT_INTO_GUEST_OS_HYPERVISOR(UUID(), 'VMware', '6.5', 'debian10_64Guest', (select id from guest_os where display_name='Debian GNU/Linux 10 (64-bit)' LIMIT 1), utc_timestamp(), 0);




**EXTRA**
**TEXT**
```

I have added line which is shown in bold, but my git diff shows changes as follows:

```
root@bhargavi-Latitude-3400:~/Accelerite-CloudPlatform# git diff diff
--git a/setup/db/db/schema-41100to41200.sql b/setup/db/db/schema-41100to41200.sql index fc84db96cb..5be1f2744f 100644
--- a/setup/db/db/schema-41100to41200.sql

+++ b/setup/db/db/schema-41100to41200.sql @@ -1363,0 +1364,2 @@ SELECT INSERT_INTO_GUEST_OS_HYPERVISOR(UUID(), 'VMware', '6.5', 'debian10_64Gues
**+EXTRA
+TEXT**

@@ -1934 +1936 @@ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cloud`.`backup_offering` (
-SET @colexist1 := (SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'cloud' AND TABLE_NAME = 'vm_instance' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'backup_offering_id'); 

+SET @colexist1 := (SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'cloud' AND TABLE_NAME = 'vm_instance' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'backup_offering_id');

@@ -1938 +1940 @@ SET @sqlcolstmt1 := if( @colexist1 > 0, 'SELECT ''INFO: column backup_offering_i
-PREPARE addstmt1 FROM @sqlcolstmt1; 
+PREPARE addstmt1 FROM @sqlcolstmt1; @@ -1943 +1945 @@ EXECUTE addstmt1;
-SET @colexist2 := (SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'cloud' AND TABLE_NAME = 'vm_instance' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'backup_external_id'); 

+SET @colexist2 := (SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'cloud' AND TABLE_NAME = 'vm_instance' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'backup_external_id');

@@ -1947 +1949 @@ SET @sqlcolstmt2 := if( @colexist2 > 0, 'SELECT ''INFO: column backup_external_i
-PREPARE addstmt2 FROM @sqlcolstmt2; 

+PREPARE addstmt2 FROM @sqlcolstmt2; @@ -1952 +1954 @@ EXECUTE addstmt2;
-SET @colexist3 := (SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'cloud' AND TABLE_NAME = 'vm_instance' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'backup_volumes'); 
+SET @colexist3 := (SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'cloud' AND TABLE_NAME = 'vm_instance' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'backup_volumes');

@@ -1956 +1958 @@ SET @sqlcolstmt3 := if( @colexist3 > 0, 'SELECT ''INFO: column backup_volumes ex
-PREPARE addstmt3 FROM @sqlcolstmt3; 
+PREPARE addstmt3 FROM @sqlcolstmt3;
```

As you observe there is no difference between changed and unchanged text as shown above.
can anyone please help me on the solution.

Comment: Does `git diff -w` show the same diff?

Comment: This may have to do with line endings. What OS are you running ? What is your config parameter : `git config core.autocrlf` ?

Comment: OS is ubuntu and git config core.autocrlf output is showing nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you've had a file with trailing spaces and IDE removed these spaces.

There is an option that configures such behavior. It can be found under Preferences | Editor | General - > "Remove trailing spaces on" and it was set to "All lines".

You've changed a line, then file got saved and IDE removed trailing spaces and this is why you observe such behavior with `git diff`

Comment: This worked for me after setting removetrailing spaces to none.Thanks a lot